# Play framework. How to check if user is authenticated or not?

Tags: scala, session, authentication, playframework-2.2

I'm new to playframework and I'm using version 2.2.2.

I'm checking the zentask sample but could somebody tell me how to check in view if user is logged in or not?

In main.scala.html I've list of links.

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="@routes.Application.newBlogpost">New blogpost</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@routes.Authentication.login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@routes.Authentication.logout">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
```

What I would like to have is that when user is logged in the logout link is shown.

My application.scala looks like this:

```
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(BlogPost.all(), blogpostForm))
  }
```

I can check that if user is allowed to access to create new blogpost:

```
def newBlogpost = IsAuthenticated { username => _ =>
    User.findByUsername(username).map { user =>
      Ok(views.html.blogpost.item(blogpostForm))
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
```

So what would be the easiest way in main.scala.html to check if user is logged in or not and show correct link based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass session to you html template and check is defined user there or not:

```
@()(implicit session: Session)

   <ul>
     @session.get("user").map { user =>
      <li><a href="@routes.Application.newBlogpost">New blogpost</a></li>
      <li><a href="@routes.Authentication.logout">Logout</a></li>
   }.getOrElse{
       <li><a href="@routes.Authentication.login">Login</a></li>
   }
   </ul>
```

Note: you have to mark request in your action as implicit.

Comment: Not working for me, I am using play2auth library want to achieve same thing for my site. @joonasj could you please help me in that ?:(